# How to display current username in Text (Jetpack Compose) using Firebase and Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

So, I have a Firebase Realtime Database with user's name. App should retrieve username of who tries to log in.

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDzE2.png)

I need to display current user's "name" in `Text()` with Jetpack Compose. To the place where `&username` in the picture below.

[Where to put user's name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R90ef.jpg)

This is what I have tried:

```
private val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
private val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
private val uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyPassTheme {
            initFirebase()
            WelcomeScreen()

            uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val snapshot = task.result
                    val username = snapshot?.child("name")?.getValue(String::class.java)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "$username",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

But in `WelcomeScreen()` I cannot update `$username` from `addOnCompleteListener`.

```
@Composable
private fun WelcomeScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(blue69),
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(605.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(5.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
            elevation = 10.dp,
            modifier = paddingModifier
                .height(2.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = widthOnTopBar, modifier = paddingModifier)
        }
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(30.dp)
            .width(1500.dp)
            .height(270.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.BottomCenter)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier,
            text = "&username",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(
                shadow = Shadow(
                    offset = Offset(2f, 2f),
                    blurRadius = 1f
                ),
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 45.sp,
                fontFamily = montserrat_bold
            )
        )
    }
```

I suppose there is something about data classes and OOP, but i do not know how to do it.

Comment: I believe your approach is not following a good architectural pattern, especially the unidirectional data flow. My suggestion is to read carefully this document here https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work, but you can try this.

We have added a `userName` state that will be updated from your `addOnCompleteListener` callback, and when it changes, it will update your `WelcomeScreen`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyPassTheme {

            var userName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            ...
            WelcomeScreen(userName)

            uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val snapshot = task.result
                    userName = snapshot?.child("name")?.getValue(String::class.java)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "$username",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your modified `WelcomeScreen`

```
@Composable
private fun WelcomeScreen(userName: String) {

    ...

    Column(
         ...
    ) {
        Text(
            ...
            text = userName,
            ...
        )
    }
}
```